# How to get powershell to attach certain file types from a directory and the latest 3 files?

Tags: powershell

I have this working partially, I can get powershell to attach the latest 3 files in this directory, but I cannot get it to only pick files based on file type or extension. My issue is that these files have no extension and are actually "files".

Can anyone help me get this script to only pick "files"

```
# Start-Process Outlook

$outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application 
$message = $outlook.CreateItem(0)
$message.To = "test@test.com" # for multiple email use ';' as separator
#$message.CC = "" # for multiple email use ';' as separator
$message.Subject = "Files $((get-date).adddays(-1).toshortdatestring())" 
$message.Body = "Attached."

$path    = "C:\Downloads"
#$lastest = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File | Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 3
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File | Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime -Descending | % { if ($_.Extension -eq ".file") {Send-Mail $_.FullName} }  
foreach ($file in $lastest)
{
    $message.Attachments.Add($file.FullName)
}

$message.Display()
```

Comment: So, something like: `Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File | ? {$null -eq $_.Extension}` work for you?

Comment: What is `Send-Mail`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I wasn't quite sure myself, was just trying to combine code from here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c64e9fa0-aead-4acc-a427-d9f7b3ae3a5c/powershell-script-to-attach-particular-file-extension-and-send-as-email?forum=ITCG.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala This doesn't work for me an unfortunately just selects any file..
Maybe we could do something so it excludes .php files?

Comment: Would they all share a similar name? Also, I don't see why the above wouldn't work, so how about: `Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File | ? {$_.Extension -eq ""}`?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I think the easier way for me to do this is to exclude .php file type. I'm a complete novice with powershell but am getting some things to work.
Can you help me with this? Looks like i still don't have it quite correct.
https://techwizard.cloud/2018/06/25/powershell-tip-copy-items-excluding-certain-file-extensions/

'$lastest = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File | Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 9 | -Recurse -Exclude $exclude
foreach ($file in $lastest)
'

Comment: this technically should be all you need if that's the case: `Get-ChildItem -Path "$path\*" -Exclude "*.php" -File | Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime -Descending `. Does that work for you?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Saving me again! I changed another part to  `-Property LastWriteTime' and it works very well.`

Comment: I'm late to the game, but `Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File -Filter "*."` will get you only the files with no extension.

Comment: I am the latest - for now :D - @TheMadTechnician your code will show files starting with a "." as well - sometimes that are files supposed to be hidden - I like the following code as it is easy to read and shows only files not having any "." - `Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File | Where-Object {-Not $_.Extension}`

Comment: @An-dir No, my code will not show files that begin with a dot, unless those files do not have an extension. It is usually recommended to allow the provider to filter items, rather than having PowerShell filter them like that.